# Properly implementing resource authorization for a RESTful API

Tags: php, api, rest, authorization, slim

My team has an API we wrote in PHP using the Slim Framework. It's being consumed by a web app and a third party mobile app.

We use the standard OAuth 2 workflow to provide access to our resources. We can see if someone is a sending a valid access token along with the API request and that part of the flow makes sense.

The stumbling block we're running into is how to most efficiently authorize access to a resource depending on the permissions of the user associated with the access token.

For the sake of simplicity let's say that we just want to ensure that the owner of the resource in question matches the owner of the access token. To me that seems like something that a route middleware would handle, for every request, before processing the request make sure that the resource owner ID matches that of the access token.

The problem in my mind is that resource permissions aren't necessarily consistent across all routes, a route isn't necessarily going to have an ID in the same section of the URI, it might not have an ID in the URI at all, etc. etc.

My current solution has been to have an authorization utility class that takes in an email and checks it against the user that's currently "logged in" (token owner).

```
class Authorization() {
    checkResourcePermissions($email) {
         if (loggedInUser->email == $email) {
             return true;
         }       
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a simplification, but what this means is that since a route middleware won't have the context of a request until that request goes through I will need to call this authorization method inside of every API route, responding with an error if necessary, etc. Our API is fairly large, essentially boiling this down to a large amount of copy and paste which always makes me very nervous.

What am I missing?

Comment: What you are looking for is externalized authorization. Look at [tag:abac] and [tag:xacml].

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going the way using a 'normal' MiddleWare:
First, let's assume you have a class 'user', where you implement your logic to access various types of resources or has specific permissions, given only the $app. It can access the request and get any information from a the HTTP request necessary to identify a single user.

```
class User{   
        private $userid=false;
        public function __construct($app){
                $this->app=$app;
                $users_mail=$this->app->request->post('email');
                //SELECT user_id FROM USERSTABLE WHERE email = $users_mail
                //$this->userid=user_id
        }
        public function ensureHasAccess($resourceID,$redirect='/noPermission'){
                if(!/*some DB Query which returns true if this user may access the given $resourceID*/)
                        $this->app->redirect($redirect)
        }
        public function ensureHasRole($role) {
                //some other permission checking, like ensureHasAccess();
        }
        public function ensureIsUser(){
                //do Something
        }
}
```

Next, you'll need a MiddleWare which is run *before* the route is dispatched, and creates an `User`-Object:

```
class UserPermissionMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware{
        public function call(){
                $this->app->request->user = new User($app);

                $this->next->call();
        }
}
```

Then, simply add this Middleware:

```
$app->add(new UserPermissionMiddleware());
```

Now, you can modify every route to check the access to a resource, while the resource id (of course) still needs to be supplied by hand, according to the route-specific code:

```
$app->get('/resource/:id',function($resourceId) use ($app){
        $app->request->user->ensureHasAccess($resourceId);
        //deliver resource
});
```

If the user is not allowed to access this resource, the whole process is interrupted (Note that redirect() is implemented using Exceptions!) and another route is executed. You'll still need some code in every single Route, but if there's no consistent way to determine the resource to be acccessed, there'll be no way around this.

Hope this helps you so far. If you have any Questions, feel free to ask!